# How do i get relative xpath from a given IwebElement in selenium using c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I have a method called GetLocator that returns the string locatorType (Id, name, tagname or eventually relative and absolute xpath) and his locatorValue retrieved from a Selenium `IWebElement` so that it can be used in a function like this:

```cs
file.WriteLine("\t\t driver.FindElement(By." + locatorType + "(\"" + locatorValue + "\")).SendKeys(Keys.Control +" + "\"a\");");
```

By now I implemented the getter of every kind of locator except for the relativeXpath, that could be useful for me in certain situations.

Can someone give me a hint on how could I get it?
Thank you